# How can I filter fields by current logged user into stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have an stored procedure where I get two different values, one is real one and the other is goal value

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IndicatorTrainingGaugeMonth]
AS
SET FMTONLY OFF
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ' ' AS MonthName,
        gd.Month,
        ISNULL(SUM(gd.Meta), 0) AS Total
    INTO 
        #Meta
    FROM
        [dbo].[Goal] g (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[GoalDetail] gd (NOLOCK) ON g.Id = gd.IdGoal
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[GoalClassification] gc (NOLOCK) ON gd.IdClassification = gc.Id
    WHERE 
        gc.Id IN (2, 7)
        AND g.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND gd.Month = MONTH(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        gd.Month

    SELECT 
        ' ' AS MonthName,
        MONTH(t.InitDate) AS Month,
        ISNULL(SUM(te.Hours), 0) AS Total
    INTO 
        #REAL
    FROM  
        [dbo].[Training] t (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[TrainingEmployee] te (NOLOCK) ON t.Id = te.IdTraining
    WHERE 
        YEAR(t.InitDate) = YEAR (GETDATE())
        AND MONTH(t.InitDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        t.InitDate

    SELECT 
        --m.MonthName
        m.Month,
        ISNULL(m.Total, 0) AS Meta,
        ISNULL(r.Total, 0) AS Real,
        --COS ((ISNULL(r.Total,0) - 0) / (ISNULL(m.Total,0) - 0) * PI() )AS Value
    FROM 
        #Meta m
    LEFT JOIN 
        #Real ON m.Month = r.Month

    DROP TABLE #Meta
    DROP TABLE #Real
END
```

There I get two values for example: Real: 20 Meta(Goal): 100

But now I want to filter these result by `UserBranch`. In my table `AspNetUsers` I have a foreign key of `BranchOfficeId`, so every user has a Branch

How can I take currentUserLogged and filter by his branch? Regards

---Update---

I get currently logged user in controller like:

```
public ActionResult IndicatorTrainingGauge()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var branchOfficeId = UserClass.GetUserBranchOfficeId(userId);

    try
    {
        result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Dashboard.IndicatorTrainingGauge(branchOfficeId));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return Content(result, "application/json");
}
```

And I catch in a class:

```
public static object IndicatorTrainingGauge(int branchOfficeId)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new EF.SA())
        {
            var month = context.IndicatorTrainingGaugeMonth().FirstOrDefault();
            var year = context.IndicatorTrainingGaugeYear().FirstOrDefault();

            return new { month, year };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Note: `IndicatorTrainingGaugeMonth` is a stored procedure.

So now what I need modified to filter my store by branch? Regards

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but it's worth mentioning that catching all exceptions and then immediately rethrowing them means your try/catch isn't really doing anything useful.

Comment: Thankyou bro @TiesonT.

Comment: You need to find out relation key for UserBranch table with  Goal or GoalDetail or GoalClassification table.

Comment: But I don´t have any relation with it. There is no way to achieve it? @Vicky_Thinking